# Automate use of SSMcustom on KFAS for Time Series daily effect

Tags: r, time-series, kalman-filter

I want to quantify the structural effect of an event in a Time Series analysis. For doing so I'm using what the `KFAS` package has to offer.

The problem is that the code seems to get a bit tricky if I want to model **simultaneously** *n* different dates, so *n* different events.

Here's some example that should clarify, I hope:

```
library(fpp2)
library(KFAS)
# required libraries
y <- hyndsight # just for the example
plot(hyndsight)
abline(v = c(19, 35, 47), col = "red", lwd = 2)
```

[image]

Let's say that I want to check if each of the "red-line" event is a "permanent shock" (ie: it changes the *level* of the hyndsight series). Now here's the model that can do that with `KFAS` functions:

```
# Z and T component for event on pos 19
aZ1 <- array(0, c(1, 1, length(y)))
aZ1[1, 1, (19 + 1):length(y)] <- 1 # 1s from pos 19(+1) forward
aT1 <- array(1, c(1, 1, length(y)))

# Z and T component for event on pos 35
aZ2 <- array(0, c(1, 1, length(y)))
aZ2[1, 1, (35 + 1):length(y)] <- 1 # 1s from pos 35(+1) forward
aT2 <- array(1, c(1, 1, length(y)))

# Z and T component for event on pos 47
aZ3 <- array(0, c(1, 1, length(y)))
aZ3[1, 1, (47 + 1):length(y)] <- 1 # 1s from pos 47(+1) forward
aT3 <- array(1, c(1, 1, length(y)))
```

And here's the actual model:

```
mod <- SSModel(y~0+SSMtrend(2, list(NA, NA))+SSMseasonal(12, NA)+
        SSMcustom(Z = aZ1, T = aT1,
                  R = matrix(0, 1, 0), Q = matrix(0, 0, 0),
                  a1 = 0, P = matrix(0), P1inf = matrix(1))+ # first event
        SSMcustom(Z = aZ2, T = aT2,
                  R = matrix(0, 1, 0), Q = matrix(0, 0, 0),
                  a1 = 0, P = matrix(0), P1inf = matrix(1))+ # second event
        SSMcustom(Z = aZ3, T = aT3,
                  R = matrix(0, 1, 0), Q = matrix(0, 0, 0),
                  a1 = 0, P = matrix(0), P1inf = matrix(1)), # third event
H = NA)

initial_val <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0) # the first 4 are always there
fit <- fitSSM(mod, intits = initial_val)
```

Now, the question is, how can I "automate" this process depending on the number of events that I want to model?

As you can see, for each event, I need to create a vector `aZ` and a vector `aT`. Those need to be passed in the model via the `SSMcustom` function, what if I have a new time series and I need to evaluate just two events, or four or more.

The problem is that I cannot keep adding `SSMcustom` to the model, I want to pass a new time series with a vector of *n* events, and automatically build the same model, except for the number of events to evaluate. Can I build a unique `SSMcustom` for all the events?

Also `initial_val` has to change, but that's less complicate it's always 4 + *n*, with *n* the number of events.

I know this question is a lot specific, maybe it's more for CrossValidated, but I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 1):

Introduce "permanent shock" variables equals to 0 before the shock and equals to 1 after the shock (one variable per shock). Then add these variables as explanatory variables (regressors) in you model and look if they are significant.

Take care that each of these variables will reduce the degree of freedom. So you may want to test the model with the same coefficient for all the shocks.